# Facing difficulties to define a type for a specific key while decoding JSON

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have come across a key `type` in the JSON added bellow,

```
{
   "id": "B2CAA3C8-077B-4A49-B5BA-206709630138",
   "markAsDoneDate": null,
   "endDate": 735025126.41189,
   "type": {
       "ascendingSort": {}
   },
   "createdAt": 726385126.411889
}
```

Kind of struggling to define any type for the key. Anything I specify it gives me a ***typeMismatch*** error.
Is there anyway to decode this kind of key?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you provide the decode/encode code?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution depends on your needs.
Let's say you have *BarBasedHabit* struct.
You can either create "wrapper" struct, *HabitType* for example.

```
struct HabitType: Decodable {
    let barBasedHabit: BarBasedHabit
}
```

and then define it in the parent decodable struct.

```
struct JsonResponse: Decodable {
     let id: String
     let markAsDoneDate: TimeInterval?
     let endDate: TimeInterval
     let type: HabitType
     let createdAt: TimeInterval
 }
```

Or you can define dictionary [String:BarBasedHabit] as type, and then take value for hardcoded String *"barBasedHabit"*.

```
struct JsonResponse: Decodable {
     let id: String
     let markAsDoneDate: TimeInterval?
     let endDate: TimeInterval
     let type: [String : BarBasedHabit]
     let createdAt: TimeInterval
}
```

Comment: Any struct with an optional type does the trick. Thanks a lot.
`struct TempStruct: Decodable {
    var string: String?
}`